# how to add a content to html from a database after inserting data from mysql no refresh php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, css

For example I am a user and I want to post a comment and after submitting it and saved to my database. The other page of the admin updates and automatically the data that I inserted displays without refreshing the page of the admin. Help please..
any code can help. Thanks. I'm using php for server-side language. Any language can help javascript or ajax.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with refresh.   
Especially if you want to display inserted data right back.

Comment: You first need to research the general mechanism - how the components fit together. If you don't understand it code will help you code yourself into a corner.\

Comment: You can use Ajax to perform this

Comment: @YourCommonSense inserted data can be displayed using the same JavaScript/AJAX that POST-ed it to the server.

Comment: @Calvin Ferrando the user pages is used for submitting comment and there is an admin page which is already open which needs to be updated without refresh rite?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$.post('path_to_your_php_script.php', function(data) {
    $('the_dom_element_you_want_to_show_the_comment_in').html(data);
});
```

Somewhere in path_to_your_php_script.php:

```
// some code to save the data
echo '<div>New comment</div>';
exit;
```

For more information, please refer to jQuery's [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) methods. You can do the same thing without jQuery, but you shouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

`yourphpfile.php` is the php file where you need to do all your database operations (in your case its insert into database).
So,basically you want to show the recently insert data in a webpage without refreshing the page, to do that, we need Ajax.

So, do your insert operation in `yourphpfile.php`, and if the insert operation is successful, just return the result (inserted data into DB) using `echo $output;exit;`
where $output = 'recently inserted data';
That's what you need to do in the php side.

Your `yourphpfile.php`:

```
<?php
//your database insert operation

    echo $output;// $output should have the inserted data
    exit;

?>
```

Now in ajax function:

You could use [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "yourphpfile.php",
                        success: function(response){
                            if(response != '') {
                                //data that I inserted displays without refreshing the page of the admin
                                $('yourDivContent').html(response);
                            } else {
                                // response error
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

In the reponse variable you would get what you have echoed in the `yourphpfile.php`.
That is $output. Then you could use the reponse varible inside ajax function and use it to insert into your HTML.

Comment: i tried this but it displayed the href url not the data inserted

Comment: your code is not that specific you can give any type of php sample name on above code of yourphpfile.php and the //data that I inserted displays without refreshing the page of the admin.. I dont get the point on what to add there.. sorry. =(

Comment: @vilmalnath - thanks for the answer i have tried that it works but how about you display it on another page that is idle. how can I display my data there also?

Comment: in otherpage.php use javascript with setInterval function to periodically check db using ajax and when modification is made show the response
or
You could use `.load` of jquery in your other page 
$("#feeds").load("yourphpfile.php", {limit: 25}, function(){
alert("The last 25 entries in the feed have been loaded");
});

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a form and you can use Ajax for sending the data to the backend. The ajax call would look in the following way:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax.php",
    data:{id:id},
    success:function(data){
            // do something if insertion into database has succeeded
    }
});
```

...and in php you write something as:

```
// Connecting to Database
mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS) or die ('Can not connect to MySQL database');

// Selecting Database
mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die ('Cant select Database');

$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']);

    if ($action == "insert")
    {       
    foreach ($recordArray as $key=>$value) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `TABLE`
                SET name = `".$_POST['name']."` 
                                SET age = `".$_POST['age']."`
                                .
                                .
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');           
    }
```